Unit Test Case running individually but failing together
I have a test case which is failing when running all together and working fine individually. I have tried adding Thread.Sleep() and also tried updating the method call to synchronous but didn't help me.
[Fact]
public async Task Should_Trigger_PublishLocationWac_Function()
{
    //Arrange
    PrepareData(out List<LocationWac> locationWacData, out SkuAndWac skuAndWac);

    Arrange(locationWacData);

    //Act
    var result = await _handler.RunAsync(skuAndWac, _mockContext.Object);

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(locationWacData.Count, result.TotalDocuments);
    Assert.Equal(locationWacData.Count, result.TotalPublished);
}

 private void Arrange(List<LocationWac> oneWacData, bool IsPublishedFailed = false, bool isException = false)
 {
     Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(ConfigConstants.BatchSize, oneWacData.Count.ToString());

     _mockloggerFactory.Setup(p => p.CreateLogger(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(_mockLogger.Object);
     _mockServiceProvider.Setup(p => p.GetService(It.IsAny<Type>())).Returns(_mockloggerFactory.Object);
     _mockContext.Setup(p => p.InstanceServices).Returns(_mockServiceProvider.Object);

     var cursorMock = new Mock<IAsyncCursor<LocationWac>>();
     cursorMock.SetupSequence(x => x.MoveNext(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
         .Returns(true)
         .Returns(false);
     cursorMock.SetupSequence(x => x.MoveNextAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
         .ReturnsAsync(true)
         .ReturnsAsync(false);
     cursorMock.SetupGet(x => x.Current).Returns(oneWacData);

     if (isException)
     {
         _mockLocationWacRepository.Setup(x => x.GetCollection().FindAsync(It.IsAny<FilterDefinition<LocationWac>>(), It.IsAny<FindOptions<LocationWac, LocationWac>>(), default))
             .ThrowsAsync(new Exception("Test exception"));
     }
     else
     {
         _mockLocationWacRepository.Setup(x => x.GetCollection().FindAsync(It.IsAny<FilterDefinition<LocationWac>>(), It.IsAny<FindOptions<LocationWac, LocationWac>>(), default))
             .ReturnsAsync(cursorMock.Object);
     }

     if (IsPublishedFailed)
     {
         _mockMessageProducer.Setup(x => x.Produce(It.IsAny<List<string>>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
             .ReturnsAsync(0);
     }
     else
     {
         _mockMessageProducer.Setup(x => x.Produce(It.IsAny<List<string>>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
          .ReturnsAsync(oneWacData.Count);
     }
 }

 private static void PrepareData(out List<LocationWac> locationWacData, out SkuAndWac skuAndWac)
 {
     locationWacData =
     [
         new LocationWac
         {
             DataPartitionKey = "sain1",
             Sku = "sku1",
             Sain = "sain1",
             WacPerUnit = 1.0m,
             LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
             VariancePercent = 0.1m,
             ProductGroup = "Food"
         },
         new LocationWac
         {
             DataPartitionKey = "sain2",
             Sku = "sku2",
             Sain = "sain2",
             WacPerUnit = 1.0m,
             LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
             VariancePercent = 0.1m,
             ProductGroup = "Food"
         }
     ];

     skuAndWac = new SkuAndWac
     {
         Sain = "sain1",
         Wac = 1.0m
     };
 }

The error I am getting while running is -
Assert.Equal() Failure: Values differ
Expected: 2
Actual:   4
The other test case which is successful-
[Fact]
public async Task RunAsync_Should_Log_BusinessException_WhenPublishingFails()
{
    //Arrange
    PrepareData(out List<LocationWac> locationWacData, out SkuAndWac skuAndWac);

    Arrange(locationWacData, true);

    //Act
    var result = await _handler.RunAsync(skuAndWac, _mockContext.Object);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(locationWacData.Count, result.TotalDocuments);
    Assert.Equal(0, result.TotalPublished);
    _mockErrorHandlingHelper.Verify(x => x.InsertErrorLogAsync(It.IsAny<ServiceNowErrorLog>()), Times.Once);
}

Can someone help me on this.

Your SubjectUnderTest has to be decoupled from anything by mocking any external dependencies. You did not - see the EnvironmentVariables

failing when running all together -> as far as I can see in the code your provided, you're only showing one test case. Please show the code for at least two test cases. That being said, @SirRufo has a point and your issue could be caused by your tests running in parallel and inadvertently sharing an env variable.

this is allmost certainly an indication for your tests being not fully decoupled. That means test1 sets some state, which test2 depends on.

@CorentinPane, added another test case in the post
